# Generated source of a page (after javascript is run)

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a question for all of you folks that do lots of actual HTML/HTML5/JavaScript type development. I know I can use Firebug and Chrome to check out rendered data for certain script element. For example

```
<td class="FUNFIELD">
<b>
   <script>
      document.write('1500');
   </script>1500
</b>
</td>
```

In the above example output from Firebug, the output of its Copy HTML functionality prints all of the HTML like the above example where it includes the Javascript that produced a certain output (`document.write('1500');`), along with the output (1500).

The functionality I want would just output “'1500” without including the script. I want something that will produce the complete computed HTML for that entire document. I don’t want it including the script or CSS code. Does anyone know of a particular tool (like the Chrome or Firebug tools) that will actually provide that?

Thanks
-Andrew

Comment: You non't need any extra tools, although using tools will make it easier. Just type `document.body.innerHTML` into the Chrome console after the script runs.

Comment: document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + document.documentElement.outerHTML.replace('<','&lt;') + '</pre>'

Comment: See: http://jsfiddle.net/11nnepym/

Comment: `document.body.textContent='<pre>'+document.documentElement.outerHTML;`